# Cannot read properties of null (reading 'drawProjectile')

Tags: javascript, html

The following code will return the error in the title:

```
<img id="frog" src="frog.png" width="50" height="50">
<script>
  var theCanvas = document.getElementById("theCanvas");
  var theContext = document.getElementById("2d");
  var theImage = document.getElementById("frog");
  var x = 300;
  var y = 50;
  moveProjectile();

  function drawProjectile() {
    theContext.drawProjectile(theImage,0,0);
  }
  function moveProjectile() {
    x += 1;
    drawProjectile();
    window.setTimeout(moveProjectile, 1000/30);
  }
</script>
```

The line in specific is the one that reads

```
TheContext.drawProjectile(theImage,0,0);
```

Comment: 1. You probably wanted to use `theCanvas.getContext('2d')`. 2. It still won't work because context doesn't have such method

Comment: Canvas context is not obtained by a call to getElementById, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/api/canvasrenderingcontext2d.  Context has a method "drawImage" but not "drawProjectile", see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage

Comment: Aside: Instead of nested `setTimeout` calls, use `requestAnimationFrame`, or at the very least `setInterval`.

Comment: One of the things you're expected to do before asking a question here is to do research. Research can include google or tutorials. The errors you have are of the sort that imply you have made little to no effort researching your issues. You might try MDN's [Canvas Tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial) as a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

Canvas context does not have a `drawProjectile` function. I believe what you are trying to do is `theContext.drawImage(theImage, 0, 0)`.

Comment: Even when I change this, the same error occurs.